# install tensorflow from jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install tensorflow from Jupyter notbook. Any reason the blow seems to be hung up.

The code I used to install it is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create virtual environment for Tensorflow

```
#create virtual environment tf and install python 
conda create -n tf python=3.9
#activate virtual env
activate tf
#install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
#install Jupyter notebook
pip install jupyter
#Launch notebook 
jupyter notebook
```

OR.
Jupyter notebook is available then just run `!pip install tensorflow` on jupyter notebook